# python - Convert a string to variable name, to which I can assign a list or pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, variables, type-conversion

I have a list of string like `L = ["V01", "V02", "V03"]` and I want to convert each element in L to a variable, to which I can assign a pd.DataFrame.

`df_list = []
    for name in L:
        df_temp = df[df['name'] == name]
        df_list.append(df_temp)
    dd = dict(zip(L, df_list))
    globals().update(dd)`

At this point `V01`, `V02`, and `V03` are recognized as variables and when keyed in, the outputs are the respective pd.DataFrame's.

Is there a way for me to reference the new variables `V01`, `V02`, and `V03` without first printing them out?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question completely. Let me attempt the solution basis my understanding of the question

You have a variable to which a string is assigned

```
name = "V01"
```

You want to assign a data frame to the string

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[name] = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["John","Simon"], "Age" : [21,30]})
```

Now you want to call that data frame without explicitly calling the string but the variable to which it is assigned

```
print(my_dict[name])

   Age  Name
0  21   John
1  30   Simon
```

Edit 1 :

```
# Creating the data frame "df1" and the list of names "L"
df = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["V01","V02","V03","V01","V02","V03"], "Age" : [21,30,21,23,45,32]})
L = ["V01", "V02", "V03"]
print(df)
    Age name
0   21  V01
1   30  V02
2   21  V03
3   23  V01
4   45  V02
5   32  V03

# Sub setting the data frame by names from "L" and storing it in a dictionary as a key-value pair
my_dict = {}
for name in L :
    my_dict[name] = df[df['name'] == name]

# Printing the data frame for "V01"
my_dict["V01"]
Output :
    Age name
0   21  V01
3   23  V01
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I editted my question in hopes of clarifying.

Comment: Thanks @Ram! Idk why it didn't immediately occur to me to make the names dictionary keys. Much easier approach.